# NestJS IntersectionType from @nestjs/swagger does not validate the combined class fields

Tags: validation, nestjs

In following up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695341/nestjs-combine-dtos-into-a-single-dto-with-swagger-support?noredirect=1#comment130153044_73695341), I am trying to ensure the validation remains and works.  However, my combined class does not validate the included fields.
For instance, I have a basic AdminCodeDTO that sepcifies the AdminCode is required, has a valid value (1-999)

```
import { IsNumber, Min, Max, IsDefined } from '@nestjs/class-validator';
import { ApiProperty, ApiResponseProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class AdminCodeDTO {
    @ApiProperty({
        description: 'Sweda Administration Code used for time tracking that is not part of a mantis.',
    })
    @ApiResponseProperty({ example: 5 })
    @IsDefined() @IsNumber() @Min(1) @Max(999) public AdminCode: number;

    constructor(AdminCode?: number) {
        this.AdminCode = AdminCode;
    }
}
```

Testing this class works, and the validation will return the errors:

```
import { validate } from '@nestjs/class-validator';
import { ValidationError } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AdminCodeDTO } from './admin-code-dto';

describe('AdminCodeDto', () => {
    let TestDTO: AdminCodeDTO;

    beforeEach( () => {
        TestDTO = new AdminCodeDTO(5);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(TestDTO).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have the AdminCode value set', () => {
        expect(TestDTO.AdminCode).toBe(5);
    });

    it('should allow creation with an empty constructor', () => {
        expect(new AdminCodeDTO()).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should generate the DTO errors', async () => {
        const DTOValidCheck: AdminCodeDTO = new AdminCodeDTO();
        const Errors: Array<ValidationError> = await validate(DTOValidCheck);
        expect(Errors.length).toBe(1);
        expect(Errors[0].constraints['isDefined']).toBe('AdminCode should not be null or undefined');
        expect(Errors[0].constraints['isNumber']).toBe('AdminCode must be a number conforming to the specified constraints');
        expect(Errors[0].constraints['max']).toBe('AdminCode must not be greater than 999');
        expect(Errors[0].constraints['min']).toBe('AdminCode must not be less than 1');
    });
});
```

To then build a simple DTO combining 2 fields to do the testing, I create a description DTO as well, to add that field for this simple example.

```
import { IsDefined, IsString, MaxLength, MinLength } from '@nestjs/class-validator';
import { ApiProperty, ApiResponseProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class DescriptionDTO {
    @ApiProperty({
        description: '',
        minLength: 3,
        maxLength: 20
    })
    @ApiResponseProperty({ example: 'Sick Day' })
    @IsDefined() @IsString() @MaxLength(20) @MinLength(3) public Description: string;

    constructor(Description?: string) {
        this.Description = Description;
    }
}
```

I then use the IntersectionType of @nestjs/swagger, to combine the AdminCodeDTO, with a new description field for the payload.

```
import { IsDefined, IsString, MaxLength, MinLength } from '@nestjs/class-validator';
import { ApiProperty, ApiResponseProperty, IntersectionType} from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { AdminCodeDTO } from './admin-code-dto';

export class AdmininstrationCodesDTO extends IntersectionType(
    AdminCodeDTO,
    DescriptionDTO
)
{
    constructor(AdminCode?: number, Description?: string) {
        this.AdminCode = AdminCode;
        this.Description = Description;

}
```

My test however, while all the columns are defined, the validation does not work.

```
import { AdmininstrationCodesDTO } from './admininstration-codes-dto';

describe('AdmininstrationCodesDTO', () => {
    let TestDTO: AdmininstrationCodesDTO;
    beforeEach( () => {
        TestDTO = new AdmininstrationCodesDTO(77, 'Test Admin Code');
    })

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(TestDTO).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should be defined when launched without parameters', () => {
        expect(new AdmininstrationCodesDTO()).toBeDefined();
    })

    it.each([
        ['AdminCode', 77],
        ['Description', 'Test Admin Code'],
    ])('should have the proper field {%s} set to be %d', (FieldName, Expected) => {
        expect(FieldName in TestDTO).toBe(true);
        expect(TestDTO[FieldName]).toBe(Expected);
    });

    // This test fails as the validation settings are not enforced.  Working on any of the DTOs directly though, the validation is confirmed.   
    it('should generate the DTO errors', async () => {
        const TestDTO: AdmininstrationCodesDTO = new AdmininstrationCodesDTO();
        const Errors: Array<ValidationError> = await validate(TestDTO, );
        expect(Errors.length).toBe(8);
    });
        
});
```

**EDIT**: This also causes a problem in my Swagger UI documentation, where this method now prevents my request schemas from showing the data.  When I define my fields directly in the DTO (without IntersectionType) the fields show up in the request schema for Swagger.  I have the CLI functions enabled in the project.json (NX monorepo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found out from your [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/10282) (thank you for that by the way) you were using `@nestjs/class-validator` and `@nestjs/class-transformer` for the validator and transformer packages. `@nestjs/mapped-types` uses the original class-valdiator and class-transformer packages and these packages use an internal metadata storage device rather than the full `Reflect` API and metadata storage, so when Nest tried to copy over the metadata from `class-validator` there was none found because of the use of `@nestjs/class-validator`, which ended up in having no metadata present for the `IntersectionType` request